# Why is my Mongoose query not updating a value in a nested array in the MongoDB databse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have tried to implement this in several ways and none seem to work.
All I need to do is change the `Status` value of a specific `Notifications` object (found by its `_id`) from `0` to `1`.

Example JSON:

```
{
    "_id": "577fbf0c7c6e88600ede5e73",
    "updatedAt": "2016-07-14T11:27:18.670Z",
    "createdAt": "2016-07-08T14:56:12.013Z",
    "Name": "Name",
    "Email": "test@test.com",
    "Notifications": [
      {
        "_id": "5787644108edec801e9cd0ab",
        "Title": "They commented on This",
        "Type": 1,
        "Status": 0,
        "TeamID": "578357109bb105602b1cba27",
        "DraftID": "578357b89bb105602b1cba2a"
      },
      {
        "_id": "578777167d1f3424251c361f",
        "Title": "He commented on That",
        "Type": 1,
        "Status": 0,
        "TeamID": "578357109bb105602b1cba27",
        "DraftID": "578357b89bb105602b1cba2a"
      }
    ]
    .....
  }
```

My route:

```
router.post('/notification', function (req, res) {
    UserProfile.update({
        'Notifications._id' : req.body.NotificationID
    }, {
        '$set' : {
            'Notifications.$.Status' : 1
        }
    }, function (err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
    })
});
```

I don't get any errors and the update doesn't seem to happen.
What could the problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the type of `Notifications._id` ObjectId? If so, try cast `req.body.NotificationId` to ObjectId. Change the query to

```
{'Notifications._id' : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.NotificationID)}
```

Comment: Yes this worked! thank you very much. Do you have a reference link where this is explained? I'm new to this so I'd like to check it out

Comment: @Poot87 Good! In mongodb and mongoose, `ObjectId` type is different from `String` type. You can check the types of mongoose at [http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema.Types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema.Types).

Answer (score 0):

Try '$set' instead of $set.
Ensure that you are getting id coming in correctly.
Update callback comes with updated document - print that to know what happens.

Comment: Do you mean this? `{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0 }`

Comment: add {'$new': true} as an argument after set - to check updated document

Answer (score 0):

The `$` is referring only the first item in the array. If you want to update all you have to use find and save:

```
UserProfile.findOne({
        'Notifications._id' : req.body.NotificationID
    }, function(err, doc) {
         _.find(doc.Notifications, {_id: req.body.NotificationID}).Status = 1;

         doc.save(function (err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
    })
})
```

Comment: It's only meant to update one specific Notification object referenced by it's _id property.

Comment: ok but it won't work since you work on the whole doc. I'll fix my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answering. It was throwing this error : `ReferenceError: _ is not defined`

Comment: it's lodash. If you don't have it use .filter